# Jess - Is there an efficient way to check if a fact is still in working memory?

Tags: java, jess

For simplicity suppose I have the following two templates:

```
(deftemplate JessObjA (declare (from-class JessObjA)) )
(deftemplate JessObjB (declare (from-class JessObjB)) )
```

and a rule which adds a JessObjB into memory whenever a match on a JessObjA happens. In addition to this, I have a list-like object in my Java program which stores these JessObjB's (either the fact-id or reference. I am undecided on this since I do not know which is better for now):

```
(defrule one-for-one
(logical
    ?x <- (JessObjA)
)
=>
    (bind ?p (new JessObjB ))
    (printout t "made a new JessObjB" ?p crlf)
    (add ?p)

    (bind ?list (fetch someList))
    (?list add ?p)
)
```

I want to keep the contents of someList up to date. I know that if I retract my JessObjA, the fact associated with JessObjB will also be retracted, but both the Fact and the JessObjB objects still remain in Java's memory (if my list holds the references).

What I want to do is to periodically check within my list if any values reference fact identifiers that are no longer in memory. My first thought is to use `(fact-id <id>)`, but that actually throws an exception if the fact no longer is in memory. On top of this, [it is a slow function](https://jess.sandia.gov/jess/docs/70/functions.html#fact-id), which I would want to avoid.

My only working solution so far is ugly: my list holds the `JessObjB` objects, and to check whether it exists as a fact or not, I call [Rete.getShadowFactForObject](https://jess.sandia.gov/doc/71/api/jess/Rete.html#getShadowFactForObject(java.lang.Object)) on it, and if I encounter a JessException, then I know it is no longer in memory, so I can remove it from the list.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do an action when some condition is met it's best to write a rule to match the condition. If you have an A but no B, the rule must: (a1) create B, (a2) insert B into the List<>. If you have a B but no A, another rule must: (b1) retract B, (b2) remove B from the List<>. As your rule "one-for-one" doesn't permit the coding of (b2), you cannot really use the "logical" CE.

Keeping the Java list up-to-date is much preferable compared to a solution using two rules.

Comment: The problem is, my actual rules for my program are more complicated than my one-for-one rule. And I am using Jess to leverage logical support. I would like to avoid creating additional rules that match on the non-existence of facts.

Comment: So why do you keep that List<B> in the first place? You can always obtain a list of all Bs by querying Working Memory. Redundancy in information is always a code smell.

Comment: So I have a set of rules, R1, R2, ...,  and each rule produces the same kinds of Facts, but I am interested in keeping track of which rule produced said Fact. I keep this information stored as a map, where the entry for key "R1" contains a List<B>, and so on. Is there a better way to do keep track of this? I should note that having different fact templates for each rule is not an option for this application in particular.